# Show that $\int_0^x \frac1{\sqrt{x_k(1-x_k)}}dx_k = 2 \arcsin (\sqrt{x}).$

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to show that 
$$\int_0^x \frac1{\sqrt{x_k(1-x_k)}}dx_k = 2 \arcsin (\sqrt{x}).$$

I know that I need to use the trigonometric substitution, and I understand another result 
$$\int_0^x \frac1{\sqrt{1-x_k^2}} dx_k = \arcsin(x).$$
But, I am not sure how to solve my original question. I would appreciate if you give some help.

Comment: $x_k$ is a rather unfriendly choice of variable name. What's wrong with $t$?

Comment: For $x=0$ the equality is true. If you differentiate both sides you get the same function. So both handsides solve the same initial value problem, therefore they are the same function.

Answer (score -1):

Make substitution $x_k=\sin^{2}\theta$. Note that $dx_k=2\sin \theta \cos \theta d\theta$. The integral becomes $\int_0^{\arcsin {\sqrt x}} 2d\theta=2\arcsin {\sqrt x}$